# Basic calculator when input is wrong error msg is supposed to appear but appears regardless of input

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to coding and decided to make a basic calculator. After I made it and it was working I decided to make text that comes up when you enter the wrong variable. I used this code but it runs regardless of what I input. Any fix would be appreciated!

```
while user_input != ("1","2","3","4"):
    print("Please enter 1, 2, 3 or 4!")
    user_input = input("Choice:")
```

Here's the full code:

```
import time

def Add(x, y):
    return x + y # x is added to y

def Sub(x, y):
    return x - y # x is subtracted by y

def Multiply(x, y):
    return x * y # x is multiplied by y

def Divide(x, y):
    return x / y # x is divided by y

print("Select a function:\n")
print("1.Add\n")
print("2.Sub\n")
print("3.Multiply\n")
print("4.Divide\n") 

user_input = input("Choice:") # user chooses function

while user_input != ("1","2","3","4"):
    print("Please enter 1, 2, 3 or 4!")
    user_input = input("Choice:")

num1 = float(input("Enter first number:")) # user unputs number
num2 = float(input("Enter second number:")) # user inputs second number

if user_input == '1':
    print(num1, "+", num2, "=", Add(num1,num2))

if user_input == '2':
    print(num1, "-", num2, "=", Sub(num1,num2))

if user_input == '3':
    print(num1, "*", num2, "=", Multiply(num1,num2))

if user_input == '4':
    print(num1, "/", num2, "=", Divide(num1,num2))

time.sleep(5) # sleeps for 5 seconds before ending
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're trying to compare a single value to a list and what you really want is to check if user_input is not inside a list of expected values. Try doing this (note the not in),

```
while user_input not in ("1","2","3","4"):
    print("Please enter 1, 2, 3 or 4!")
    user_input = input("Choice:")
```